Is there a way to make a new .txt file in Flask?
I'm trying to have the user results (which are in a dict as objects) to be written to a new text file in the folder dl_files, with a user-inputted text sequence as part of the filename. The application will then download the newly created file to the user (using send_file)
However, I can't find a way to create a new txt file on demand in Flask.
My current code looks like this:
    username = (request.form["username"].replace(" ","_")
                .replace("\n","_").lower())
    filename = "dlfiles/"+username+"_results.txt"
    filename = os.path.abspath(filename)
    with open(filename,"w") as f:
        f.write(("dictkey='stickers,username="+username))
        for x in dict:
            f.write(dict[x].export_form())

(The .export_form() is a function in my class to get the correct text for writing into the file).
When I try to run this code, however, I get a FileNotFoundError. Even using an alternate method (x function in with open()) doesn't make a new file.

What line throws FileNotFoundError?

@matszwecja the "with open(filename,"w") as f:, as it says the file doesn't exist (because it doesn't make the file it's trying to write to)

Please add full traceback for the error

Most likely, your dlfiles directory does not exist. You can use os.mkdir(directory_path) to create it. I also strongly recommend not using dict as a variable name, since it is a built-in name and can lead to unexpected behavior. Hope this helps!

@VictorEgiazarian I referenced the wrong directory, changing the name to match fixed it. Thanks for the help! I will also adjust the dict name, thanks for the advice
